# Explicit exclude of a property in entity framework core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

currently i have some performance issues in entity framework core. I read a lot of data with the following function:

```
Database.OperatingInstructionReferences.Include(x => x.OperatingInstruction).Include(x => x.State).Where(x => x.OperatingInstruction.Department.Id == user.Department.Id && (x.OperatingInstruction.Type.Equals(type) || x.OperatingInstruction.Type.Equals(ManageNavPageInstruction.ListProduct))).ToList();
```

This operation is really slow because in the class / object of OperatingInstruction is a really long string with a lot of payload. The string-property is called Content. Could i explicit exlude only this string property?

Maybe something like this:

```
Database.OperatingInstructionReferences.Include(x => x.OperatingInstruction.Exclude(y=>y.Content)).Include(x => x.State).Where(x => x.OperatingInstruction.Department.Id == user.Department.Id && (x.OperatingInstruction.Type.Equals(type) || x.OperatingInstruction.Type.Equals(ManageNavPageInstruction.ListProduct))).ToList();
```

I know there is a possibility by using the select-function, but i am looking for something else. I need every other property than the content-property - so i think the select-function is a little bit overhead because i have to declare every other stuff.

Maybe someone could help me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you can use the SqlQuery for this.

Comment: You can use `Select(r=> new {` to select a new anonymous object that excludes the property you mentioned, Or you can have 2 entities that map to the same table, one with the property and the other without. And FYI we usually prefer separating the actual table and the CLOB like values in the database.

Comment: @Eldar if there is another possibility i wouldn't use the select. I know this function but it is really much overhead because i like to get every other property than the content property. In this case could you explain the possibility with "same database-table with two classes"?

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-2.1) document

Answer (score 0):

A simple and reusable way to implement this is to create a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types), that represents a "view" of the data you want to query. In your case, the "view" would obmit the `Content` property.

You can decide yourself, whether you want to implement an actual database-side view for this new keyless entity (using `.ToView()`) or just mapping it the underlying table (using `.ToTable()`) while not defining the `Content` property on the model class (or explicitly ignoring it via data annotation or FluentAPI).

See [Keyless Entity Types: Mapping to database objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#mapping-to-database-objects) for further information.